# how do I force client side changes for style sheets?

Tags: html, css

I've been making a lot of changes recently and I need a way to force style sheet changes on the client side.  Is there a recommended way to do this?

Comment: When you say force what do you mean? Change the styles after the page has loaded or reload the modified style sheet?

Comment: What do you mean 'style sheet changes on the client side?' Do you mean cached stylesheets?

Comment: What do you mean? Stylesheet changes are reflected when someone views your page, unless there is a style that already trumps the one you added. i.e. if it's more specific, or if there are inline styles, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **?v=x.y** to the end of the link to your stylesheet.

http://www.zadling.com/2010/08/css-trick-force-users-to-see-new-stylesheet/

Comment: If he means he wants to overwrite their cached copy as he makes incremental updates, this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It's exactly what I need.  Easy yet effective...love it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just send a nocache-header (set it to expire in 1990) and the page should be loaded directly instead of from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Add an expires header to your site, but change the value to a date in the past forcing them to redownload the site from scratch and thus clearing there cache,

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-expires.html

It can be done in apache, php, and others, I would use apache.

Answer (score 0):

You could always timestamp or version your CSS, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?141211" />
```

Or with versions

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?ver=2" />
```